# Mercurial - How to View Revision with TextMate?

Tags: mercurial, textmate

I understand that I can print a revision in the terminal with `hg cat filename -r`, but it is often convuluted and hard to read in the terminal window.

Is there a way I can open a revision with textmate from terminal, similar to using `mate filename`?

I'd prefer not to have to export the revision, and then open it up in textmate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mate -` to read from `stdin`. So you can use `hg cat filename -r rev | mate -`.

However, the TextMate Mercurial bundle is enabled by default, so if you're already viewing the file in TextMate, use **Bundles** > **Mercurial** > **View Revision** (or <kbd>⌘Y</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>) to pick an older revision to view instead.

Comment: Thanks.  All of my Mercurial bundle short-cuts are set to ⌃⇧M though :(.  Did you manually set up your short-cuts or did they come set already?

Comment: That's how they came set.  I just downloaded a fresh copy of TextMate from macromates.com yesterday to answer your question; I'd actually never used it before.